# How can I get my jQuery function for work for each element inside a foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a foreach loop displaying posts, all of them with a comment button

```
<button type="button" class="commentbtn" id="comment">
    <i class="em em-thought_balloon"></i>
</button>
```

The function itself is working fine, but only for the most recent post displayed, not the other ones. I'm trying to get it to work when each post comment button is clicked separately. This is the function

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#commentform").hide();
    $("#comment").click(function(event) {
        $("#commentform").show();
    });
});
```

Any ideas how I can fix this easily?

Edit: Here's the HTML I'm using, it's Laravel Collective

```
 {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST','class'=>'commentForm']) !!}
 {!! Form::textarea('Comment', null, ['size'=>'50x2']) !!}
 {!! Form::button('Comment', ['type'=>'submit', 'class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
 {!! Form::button('Cancel', ['class'=>'btn btn-default cancelComment']) !!}
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: `id` of element in `document` should be unique

Comment: id should be unique, either use class to attach event or if you can't make id unique and want to attach event using it then can use `$("[id='comment']"`

Comment: Where and what is `#commentform`? Need more HTML

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#commentform").hide();
$(".commentbtn").each(function(index){
    $(this).click(function(event) {
        $(this).next().find(".commentform").show();
    });
});
```

This will work when any button is pressed.

Update: I changed the `#commentform` id selector to `.commentform`.

This will work if your `.commentform` is below the button.

---

**UPDATE:**

I don't know laravel but I guess the resulting html for the form you provided is is:

```
  <form method="POST" class="commentForm">
     <textarea name="Comment" cols="50" rows="2"></textarea>
     <button name="Comment" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Comment</button>
     <button name="Cancel" class="btn btn-default cancelComment">Cancel</button>
  </form>
```

And the comment button you said earlier:

```
  <button type="button" class="commentbtn" id="comment">
     <i class="em em-thought_balloon"></i>
  </button>
```

This is your solution with plain js, it hides each form and it displays each one when you click the `.commentbtn` button:

```
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
     document.querySelectorAll('.commentForm').forEach(form => {
        form.style.display = 'none'; // Hide all the forms
     });
     document.querySelectorAll('.commentbtn').forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', event => {
           // Show the corresponding form
             event.target.parentNode.querySelector('.commentForm').style.display = 'block';
        });
     });
  });
```

And the jquery version:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.commentForm').each(function(index){
        $(this).hide(); // Hide all the forms
     });
     $('.commentbtn').each(function(index){
        // Show the corresponding form
        $(this).parend().find('.commentForm').show();
     });
  });
```

This will ONLY work if you wrap each form - button html with a container like this:

```
  <div>
     <form method="POST" class="commentForm">
        <textarea name="Comment" cols="50" rows="2"></textarea>
        <button name="Comment" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Comment</button>
        <button name="Cancel" class="btn btn-default cancelComment">Cancel</button>
     </form>
     <button type="button" class="commentbtn" id="comment">
        <i class="em em-thought_balloon"></i>
     </button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Yes, when I click any button it opens up the form like I was wanting. However, it's for some reason only displaying my form in the most recent post. When I click on comment for later posts, the form opens only in the most recent post

Comment: I updated the code. Add a class `commentform` for each of your forms. Btw can you show us how did you code your commentform in html? That would help a lot because I need to know where is the form located.

Comment: I've updated my answer above, take a look at it and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

You are using same ID  multipal time to bind via loop. Dont Do this. Use class.

```
$(".commentform").hide();
    $(".commentbtn").click(function(event) {
       $(this).next().find('.commentform').show();
  });
```

Comment: Yeah but in the code he provided he doesn't show any class `.commentbtn` that's why I used `#commentform` in my answer

Comment: @MerunasGrincalaitis Then add a class to the HTML. Don't use an `id` to represent multiple elements. That's the whole reason for this bug. And it may be browser-dependent.